# Seeking boneless legs and arms story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Seeking a short horror story from an anthology from maybe the 1970s. A traveller enters a house and finds, in the basement, women whose arm and leg bones have been removed but they are still alive.

Comment: Jennie, how many women without bones does the traveller find in the basement, one or several?

Comment: @user14111 Agreed, on second read, I think "women" *was* intended. Thanks. Also, yes I did think that "they" was referring to the bones.

Comment: It's not wht you're looking for, but here's some [boneless *men.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Without_Bones)

Comment: @Jennie: It sounds familiar, but I can't place it. The women were sort of tricked or persuaded to give up their bones by a Cassanova type man?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be "The House of Horror" by Seabury Quinn. In the end of the story, the narrator descends into the basement of a house and finds kidnapped young women who have been kept in cages. They have been surgically altered and turned into monsters by amputating their limbs, removing bones, gouging out eyes, cutting off ears etc.